# Good opensource WPF applications

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, n-tier-architecture, wcf-data-services

I have experience with Silverlight + MVVM + WCF RIA. My next project will be developing by WPF and its architecture is 3-tiers. I want to know are there good example for this kind of project?

Comment: Look around http://codeplex.com

Comment: Bit old but related: [Good example WPF applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534328/good-example-wpf-applications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MVVM is pretty cool and here is a MVVM lite which make your developement more easier. 
http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/#intro

Also, I recommend to check the project "Ribbon for WPF" which uses binding a lot. You can download from "http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2bfc3187-74aa-4154-a670-76ef8bc2a0b4" which comes with the source code and samples.

Comment: These are not applications at all. These are components at best.

Comment: The source code also includes a sample app that uses the Ribbon component.

Comment: Even so, they are in no way a full demonstration of the technologies the asker is looking for.

Comment: Did you try the sample anyway? It uses binding a lot. And binding is one key part of the MVVM pattern. Everyone can learn st. from the sample. The answer here is a recommendation, maybe it doesn't help you, but it helps someone else.